# How to write the offset's reference in excel?

Tags: ms-office, offset

The cell `d2` contains a number ,suppose it is `4`.
I want to set the offset's reference as `a5`.
`"a"&text(d2+1,0)` can express string `a5`,i want to call data in range from `a5` until  `a9`.

```
OFFSET("a"&text(d2+1,0),0,0,5,1)
```

Why offset function in excel can't accept `"a"&text(d2+1,0)` as `a5`?
How to fix the offset function expression in excel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the INDIRECT function if you want to convert a `string` into a `reference`,

```
INDIRECT(ref_text, [a1])
```

so in your example:

```
OFFSET(INDIRECT("a"&text(d2+1,0)),0,0,5,1)
```

see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261 for more details

However given offset takes,... offsets! you could just have a1 as the base and use the 4 to actually specify an offset., ie

```
OFFSET(a1,d2,0,5,1)
```